# Calling a Private Sub from another module

Tags: vba, excel

I have two modules, Module1 and Module2.

In Module1:

```
Private Function myCheck() As Boolean

if [Operation] = [Something] then

myCheck = True
Else
myCheck = False
End if

End Sub
```

In Module2, I would like to run myCheck sub in Module 1 then do another operation:

```
Private Sub Execute()

[Operation 1]

If myCheck = True Then

[Operation 2]
Else
[Operation 3]

End If
End Sub
```

It does not work. If I place Private Function myCheck within the same module then it works. Is there a special method to call a sub or function from another module?

Comment: change `Private` to `Public`, or really just erase the `Private` and it will be public.

Comment: Is that the only way? The whole point of it being private is to hide it from users..

Comment: making it `Private` means the function is *only* available to the module where it's stored.

Comment: okay - put that in answer and I will mark as correct. Thanks

Comment: @Oday if you want to _hide it from users_ then you should add that info to your questions.  See Stax's answer for the solution

Answer (score 8):

Use Option Private Module For Module1, then in Module 2:

for a *Sub*; qualify what you're calling with the Module it's in, like so:

```
Module1.myCheck()
```

for a *Private* Sub; use Application.Run and qualify what you're calling with the Module it's in, like so:

```
Application.Run ("Module1.myCheck")
```

Using Private Module hides it's contained sub/s in the Developer > Macros list.

---

*Further Reading :-)*

Read through the comments in the code below to see what does and doesn't work.
To confirm the behaviours yourself:
Create a new Excel, open Developer > Visual Basic, insert 3 Modules.
Copy the below code blocks into the relevant modules.

```
'In Module1
Option Explicit

Sub ScopeTrials()

'NOTES:
'   Only NormalSubIn_NormalModule shows in Developer > Macros.

'   As the default without a keyword is Public I have called
'   these "Normal". I.e. you can use Public or Nothing wherever
'   Normal is.

'   A line commented out shows what doesn't work.

NormalSubIn_NormalModule
Call NormalSubIn_NormalModule
Application.Run ("NormalSubIn_NormalModule")  'Not recommended!

NormalSubIn_PrivateModule
Call NormalSubIn_PrivateModule
Application.Run ("NormalSubIn_PrivateModule")  'Not recommended!

'PrivateSubIn_NormalModule
'Call PrivateSubIn_NormalModule
'Module2.PrivateSubIn_NormalModule
'Call Module2.PrivateSubIn_NormalModule
Application.Run ("PrivateSubIn_NormalModule")  'Fails with duplicates! See Explanation
Application.Run ("Module2.PrivateSubIn_NormalModule")

'PrivateSubIn_PrivateModule
'Call PrivateSubIn_PrivateModule
'Module3.PrivateSubIn_PrivateModule
'Call Module3.PrivateSubIn_PrivateModule
Application.Run ("PrivateSubIn_PrivateModule")  'Fails with duplicates! See Explanation
Application.Run ("Module3.PrivateSubIn_PrivateModule")

'Explanation: if there is an identical sub in another Private Module, then this fails
'with Runtime Error 1004 (Macro not available or Macros Disabled), which is Misleading
'as the duplication and/or nonspecified module is the problem.
'I.e. always specify module!
'Also, this only fails when the line is actually run. I.e. Compile check doesn't find this
'when starting to Run the code.

End Sub
```

---

```
'In Module2
Option Explicit



Sub NormalSubIn_NormalModule()  'only THIS sub shows in Developer > Macros

    MsgBox "NormalSubIn_NormalModule"

End Sub


Private Sub PrivateSubIn_NormalModule()

    MsgBox "PrivateSubIn_NormalModule"

End Sub
```

---

```
'In Module3
Option Explicit
Option Private Module


Sub NormalSubIn_PrivateModule()

    MsgBox "NormalSubIn_PrivateModule"

End Sub


Private Sub PrivateSubIn_PrivateModule()

    MsgBox "PrivateSubIn_PrivateModule"

End Sub
```

Comment: Using `Option Private Module` (at module scope) and `Public Sub ...`  makes the `Sub` visible in other modules, but invisible in Excel Macro list - Alt-F8.  I think that's was the OP wants...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Application.Run` to do this:

```
Application.Run "Module1.myCheck"
```

The macro will stay "invisible" for the users if they display the Macros Dialog Box (Alt+F8), since it's still private.

**Edit #1**

A second option is to introduce a dummy variable as an optional parameter in the `Sub`, like this:

```
Public Sub notVisible(Optional dummyVal As Byte)
    MsgBox "Im not visible because I take a parameter, but I can be called normally."
End Sub
```

This too, will hide the macro in the Macros Dialog Box (Alt+F8), but it can now be invoked the usual way.

Comment: Note: `Optional` parameter must not be a `Variant` in order to hide the sub from the Macros box

Comment: @chris neilsen True, thanks for pointing this out. However, since we're using a dummy variable in this case, I simply recommend `Byte` as it takes up the least memory.